# PhpWord spaceAfter Not Working

Tags: php, phpword

I'm having trouble getting `spaceAfter` and `spaceBefore` to work in `PHPWord`.

If I **DO NOT** include `spaceAfter` or `spaceBefore` in the paragraph styles, then the section will have some space before and after.

If I **DO** include `spaceAfter` or `spaceBefore` then the space goes to 0, no matter what I put in for the spacing.

I can get other paragraph styles to work at the same time, `lineHeight` for example works fine.

example:

```
$section->addText(
    "Some Text",
    array(
        "italic" => true
    ),
    array(
        "lineHeight" => 2.0,  //Works fine

        //I don't put all of these at once
        //I just want to show some of the different parameters I've used
        //And I've done the same with spaceAfter
        "spaceBefore" => 1.0,
        "spaceBefore" => "1.0",
        "spaceBefore" => .5,
        "spaceBefore" => ".5"
    )
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add it as "twip", like this:

```
'spaceBefore' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::pointToTwip(6))
```

`Converter` class also has methods `inchToTwip` and `cmToTwip`.

More info on twip:

> The base length unit in Open Office XML is twip. Twip means “TWentieth of an Inch Point”, i.e. 1 twip = 1/1440 inch.